# Transact Sql Column not null

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2014

Right now, I have a view that looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwContaminationHistory]
AS
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
        MAX(DetectorID) AS DetectorID,
        MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP,
        MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType,
        MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
        MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
    FROM 
        ContaminationHistory
    GROUP BY 
        DetectorID, ScannerType,
        YEAR(TIMESTAMP), MONTH(TIMESTAMP), DAY(TIMESTAMP),
        DATEPART(HOUR, TIMESTAMP)
GO
```

This returns these rows:

```
Row   DetectorID    TimeStamp                     ScannerType   Pollution   VFactor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2        948    2017-03-17 12:44:34.0000000 +01:00   hbd1          0          99
3        948    2017-03-17 13:01:49.0000000 +01:00   hbd1          0          99
4        948    2017-03-17 14:04:29.0000000 +01:00   hbd1          0          99
5        948    2017-03-17 12:44:34.0000000 +01:00   hbd2          0          99
6        948    2017-03-17 13:01:49.0000000 +01:00   hbd2          0          99
```

It returns 1 row for every new hour.

Now, the column `Row` is `Not Null`. This is good. However I want the same for the column `TimeStamp`.

What I tried to do is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwContaminationHistorydateee]
AS
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
        MAX(DetectorID) AS DetectorID,
        ISNULL(MIN(TIMESTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP), '1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP,
        MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType,
        MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
        MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
    FROM 
        ContaminationHistory
    GROUP BY 
        DetectorID, ScannerType,
        YEAR(TIMESTAMP), MONTH(TIMESTAMP), DAY(TIMESTAMP),
        DATEPART(HOUR, TIMESTAMP)
GO
```

However, when I excecute this, I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwContaminationHistorydateeee,
>   Line 15
>   Column 'ContaminationHistory.TimeStamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I remove the Year, Month, Day and Hour group by, and replace them with TimeStamp. the view works. But then it does not group by Timestamp, and it will give me for example 15 results per hour. While I want 1.

How can I turn the `TimeStamp` column into `NOT NULL` and keep the group by clause as I have it now?

***Update:***

I changed the view to:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwContaminationHistorydate2] 
AS
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row, 
        MAX(DetectorID) as DetectorID, 
        ISNULL(MIN(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp), '1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') as TimeStamp, 
        MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType, 
        MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
        MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
    FROM 
        ContaminationHistory 
    GROUP BY 
        DetectorID, ScannerType, 
        YEAR(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
        MONTH(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
        DAY(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
        DATEPART(HOUR, ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00'))
 GO
```

And still get the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwContaminationHistorydate2,
>   Line 14
>   Column 'ContaminationHistory.TimeStamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When i run this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwContaminationHistory2]
AS
SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
    MAX(DetectorID) AS DetectorID,
    MIN(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')) AS TIMESTAMP,
    MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType,
    MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
    MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
FROM ContaminationHistory
GROUP BY DetectorID,
    ScannerType,
    YEAR(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    MONTH(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DAY(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DATEPART(HOUR, ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00'))
GO
```

The results are correct. However the row TimeStamp is set to null, and i want it to be Not Null.

[image]

Comment: The TimeStamp column is showing as NOT NULL

Comment: Sorry, wrong one. I will edit my question

Comment: Got it, Makeing the changes now, Try this, "ISNULL(MIN(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP" The trick is that the ISNULL has to be on the outside before SQL Server will understand that the resulting value can never be NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This and hope it works for you

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwContaminationHistory]
AS
SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
    MAX(DetectorID) AS DetectorID,
    ISNULL(MIN(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP,
    MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType,
    MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
    MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
FROM ContaminationHistory
GROUP BY DetectorID,
    ScannerType,
    YEAR(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    MONTH(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DAY(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DATEPART(HOUR, ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00'))
GO
```

Or you could just do this

```
SELECT Row,
    DetectorID,
    ISNULL(TIMESTAMP, '1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP,
    ScannerType,
    Pollution,
    VFactor
FROM [dbo].[vwContaminationHistory]
```

Sample Run --

```
;WITH cte_SampleData(Row,DetectorID,TimeStamp,ScannerType,Pollution,VFactor) AS
(
SELECT 2,948,'2017-03-17 12:44:34.0000000 +01:00','hbd1',0,99 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,948,'2017-03-17 13:01:49.0000000 +01:00','hbd1',0,99 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,948,'2017-03-17 14:04:29.0000000 +01:00','hbd1',0,99 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,948,'2017-03-17 12:44:34.0000000 +01:00','hbd2',0,99 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,948,NULL,'hbd2',0,99 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,948,'2017-03-17 13:01:49.0000000 +01:00','hbd2',0,99
)
--SELECT * FROM cte_SampleData
SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
    MAX(DetectorID) AS DetectorID,
    ISNULL(MIN(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP,
    MAX(ScannerType) AS ScannerType,
    MAX(Pollution) AS Pollution,
    MAX(VFactor) AS VFactor
FROM cte_SampleData
GROUP BY DetectorID,
    ScannerType,
    YEAR(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    MONTH(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DAY(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),
    DATEPART(HOUR, ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00'))
```

Comment: The view works, however it works exactly the same as the first one i had.

The TimeStamp row is still nullable

Comment: @Mitch,I just added the sample code and as you can see it works. Please can you confirm if you are calling the correct View the one you modified. Also, some sample data can help, please use my code above to add some data for the cte_SampleData resultset

Comment: I'm getting the right results, Hower: The TimeStamp column has the following values: "TimeStamp (datetimeoffset(7), null)". And i want the null to change to Not Null

Comment: @Mitch, apologies but I don't think I understand your question. The ISNULL will handle the NULL

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and also reproduce the error so we can look at what could be the issue. Thanks

Comment: I made a edit including a image. The extra data is not needed, because the view that you made is working correctly. However the TimeStamp row is set to NULL. And i want it to be NOT NULL

Comment: Excellent, I just checked you screen grab and the column is set to NOT NULL as per your requirement, Also since we are handling Nulls, there is no chance for the view to ever return NULL.

Comment: I edited the question. Also it's true that it can't return a NULL. However, my application wants the row to be set to NOT NULL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138798/discussion-between-gouri-shankar-aechoor-and-mitch).

Comment: Understood, Apologies it took me some time to understand. Try this, "ISNULL(MIN(ISNULL(TIMESTAMP,'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00')),'1900-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00') AS TIMESTAMP" The trick is that the ISNULL has to be on the outside before SQL Server will understand that the resulting value can never be NULL

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

```
ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DetectorID), 9999) AS Row,
```

Is very weird. Row_Number always returns you some value, so it's never would be null. If you want be sure in case when DetectorId would be NULL, you should write:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL (DetectorID, 9999)) AS Row,
```

But you need remember then all NULL's DetectorId will be last rows.

Secondly:
I would make it with subquery, some like this:

```
DECLARE @Sample Table
(
    DetectorId Int, TimeStamp DateTime, ScannerType Varchar (50), Pollution Int, VFactor Int
)

Insert Into @Sample Values 
 (1, '2017-03-17 12:44:34', 'aaa', 10, 1220)
,(1, '2017-03-17 12:44:34', 'aaa', 43, 1520)
,(1, '2017-03-17 12:44:34', 'aaa', 12, 7220)
,(1, NULL, 'aaa', 10, 120)
,(1, '2017-03-17 12:51:34', 'aaa', 12, 500)
,(1, '2017-03-17 12:57:34', 'aaa', 14, 1000)
,(1, '2017-03-17 13:44:34', 'aaa', 10, 120)
,(1, '2017-03-17 14:44:34', 'aaa', 10, 120)
,(NULL, '2017-03-17 14:54:34', 'aaa', 10, 120)

--SELECT * 
--FROM @Sample

SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL (X.DetectorID, 9999)) AS Row
    ,Max (X.DetectorID) As DetectorId
    --,X.TimeStampRowNumber
    ,X.TimeStamp As TimeStamp
    ,Max (X.ScannerType) As ScannerType
    ,Max (X.Pollution) As Pollution
    ,Max (X.VFactor) As VFactor
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DetectorID AS DetectorID,
        RANK ()  
        OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY
                 DATEPART (YEAR, TimeStamp)
                ,DATEPART (MONTH, TimeStamp)
                ,DATEPART (DAY, TimeStamp)
                ,DATEPART (HOUR, TimeStamp)
            ORDER BY 
                ISNULL (TimeStamp, DATEFROMPARTS (1990, 01, 01))
        ) AS TimeStampRowNumber,
        ISNULL (TimeStamp, DATEFROMPARTS (1990, 01, 01)) As TimeStamp,
        ScannerType AS ScannerType,
        Pollution AS Pollution,
        VFactor AS VFactor
    FROM 
        @Sample --ContaminationHistory
) AS X
WHERE X.TimeStampRowNumber = 1
Group By 
    X.DetectorID, X.TimeStamp

ORDER BY 1
```

So.. first you need to make additional column which gave you all first measurements from each hour and then add condition.
I hope I understand what kind of result you want to get.